# How to find a record and insert the same record in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here I want to get a record and I need to insert the same record with slight modification. But I can't see the data in my new record which I found in my get record. Here is what I tried, can anyone help me? I think the problem is with this line `var institution = new Institution(data);`:

```
 Institution.find({_id:i._id}).exec(function (err, result) {
               if(result)
                transferData(result);
              }
            });
          });
      }

      function transferData(data){
         var institution = new Institution(data);
          institution.name = 'xxxx';
          institution.save(function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              return res.status(400).send({ message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
            } else {
              console.log('Data Inserted Successfully');
            }
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** returns an array of docs that match the criteria in the callback hence the line

```
var institution = new Institution(data);
```

will not work as it's expecting a Document not an array.

You could use **[`findById()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)** method as:

```
Institution.findById(i._id).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (result) transferData(result);
});          

function transferData(data) {
    var institution = new Institution(data);
    institution.name = 'xxxx';
    institution.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
        } else {
            console.log('Data Inserted Successfully');
        }
    });
}
```

---

A much better approach would involve the **[`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** method:

```
Institution.findByIdAndUpdate(i._id, {name: 'xxxx'}, {upsert: true}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
    } else {
        console.log('Data Inserted Successfully');
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi chridam,will this method ,findByIdAndUpdate insert a new record?

Comment: Yes, if you specify the `{upsert: true}` option as a parameter, like in the above edit.

Comment: Chidram,its not inserting a new reocrd but updatin,I am sorry if i failed to explain properly,my requirement is if i find a record,then the same record should be inserted as new one with name change.